# What are X apps in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, system, architecture

I was monitoring my system using Netdata today, and noticed that, some kind of X apps are using more CPU than other applications.
 [image: Netdata Monitoring]

Look clearly in the image, X is taking a larger CPU% time than others.
Not only CPU, but everything like Disk, Swap, Net, Memory and Processes.

I searched for it on the web, but I couldn't get a clear view.
Please explain.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X is your display server that shows all the graphics on your screen. [See more on Wikipedia about Xorg.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server)

Comment: only graphics or system processes also ?

Comment: It has a number of features, but primarily its used to simply show everything on your screen. The spikes in your graph are probably when you open a new web page, load a video or app, etc.

Comment: Also note the CPU percentage usage. CPU usage of 100%+ maybe okay. It depends on how many cores you have on your CPU. Keeping it simple, you have 100% of each core to use, so if you have 4 cores on your system, you have 400% to play with. So it is only concerned if you see stuff using up to 400%. X using 100% here and there means it is only using one core for a short period of time, which is normal. I would need to know more about your hardware though to help you. Usually in Linux we use system load as a better way of determining how utilized a system is.

Comment: thanks for this extra info, it was explanatory to many things